# index not allowing null values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a migration to my application like this:

```
class ChangeColumnsOnSuppliersAndStores < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_index :suppliers, :nickname, unique: true
  end
end
```

Then I started to have a problem not succeeding to create a Supplier. With the error:

```
3.0.2 :010 > x.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors [#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=nickname, type=taken, options={:value=>nil}>]>
```

It seems like the error is that the nickname already exists.

So I created another migration to allow null, again..

```
class AllowNullOnNicknameOnSuppliers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    change_column :suppliers, :nickname, :string, null: true
  end
end
```

And the error still there.

What it seems to me is that he is considering 'null' as a value that cannot be duplicated, when in fact he should not consider null but rather if the field is filled with some value, then yes... any value other than null cannot be duplicated.

---

That's how my model looks like:

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products


  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :nickname

  validates :nickname, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true
  
  def nome
    self.nickname.present? ? self.nickname : self.name
  end
end
```

seems that my dear friend @dbugger found the problem. I solved removing the second validation and setting allow_nil on the first validation like this:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :nickname, allow_nil: true

  # validates :nickname, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true
```

Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Does your model code have any validations?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: you have two uniqueness validations of nickname BTW

Comment: Additionally to allow `nil` in `uniqueness` you can use `validates :nickname, uniqueness: {allow_nil: true}`. The `validates` method is sort of a swiss army knife for all of the validators so when you call the above it will transform that into `validates_uniqueness_of :nickname, allow_nil: true`. This allows you to specify multiple validations for the same attribute on the same line e.g. `validates :nickname, uniqueness: {allow_nil: true}, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 14}` will call both `validates_uniqueness_of` with its arguments and `validates_length_of` with its arguments